# Does Twitter enforce oauth_timestamp?

Tags: language-agnostic, oauth, twitter, nonce

In the guts of OAuth I discover the field `oauth_timestamp`, for which the specified behavior is apparently that all requests that contain a lower `oauth_timestamp` value than the highest one ever received should be denied.  As I am trying to queue up a number of Twitter API requests for processing, and potentially out-of-generated-order processing for that matter, this nasty little item may really ruin my day.

But, Twitter being Twitter, there is hope: the possibility that they have never actually written code to enforce the specified behavior of `oauth_timestamp`.  Which would be lovely, since I object to it violently.

So, does anybody happen to know whether the Twitter API actually enforces `oauth_timestamp`'s specified behavior?

Comment: How about generating the OAuth parameters when the request is actually done?

Comment: @Arvin: It's more effort than doing it when queueing them up, but not unreasonably so.  The problem is that, because I have multiple worker processes handling the queue, it doesn't eliminate the issue, it just converts it to a matter of a race condition.  So I'd like to know whether the issue actually exists in context before going to the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter restricts oauth_timestamp to be within five minutes on either side of GMT. Outside of that 10 minute window and the requests will fail.

Comment: Okay, that's cool.  Are you saying, then, that it does not enforce the ascending order constraint?

Comment: I'm almost certain Twitter does not care about order. Just as long as the timestamp is fresh.

Comment: Any links to Twitter docs that state this?  I can't find any.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/twitter-development-talk/g5N01mF6_jY/9EK0MBI8tzQJ